# How to populate a data structure list?

Tags: c++, stl

So, I have this program that uses the STL list:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

const int numberOfStudents = 3;

struct StudentInfo {
    string name;
    int grade;



    };

void populateStudentRecords(list<StudentInfo>Students,list<int>::iterator iter){


}



int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    list<StudentInfo>Records;
    list<int>::iterator iter;




    return 0;
}
```

My question is how do I populate the list that has the StudentInfo data structure as a type, in which the structure has the string name and the integer grade? How do I alter these two variables for each instance of the structure in the list?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: @NathanOliver I tried using a basic for loop, such as: for(int x = 0; x < numberOfStudents; x++), but that did not work, I got something about [int] not being acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (auto it = Records.begin(); it != Records.end(); ++it) {
    it->name = ...
    it->grade = ...
}
```